# How to save models in memory in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, memory, model

I want to save the models in memory so next time I don't need to load the models again for time concerns. Right now I am using Azure Function to create a server-less application, so is there any methods I can use to save the models in memory? Because the models loading time is a lot.

Comment: What Models are you referring to? Can you provide more information

Comment: It is the machine leaning models that I saved on my disk. For example, the pickled support vector machine models. And loading these models taking so long time and I want to save all these models in memory so that next request of making predictions will save the time of loading models.